# On new linux kernel 5.8rc7 in Ubuntu 20 docker will not start

Tags: kernel, 20.04, iptables, docker

I have installed the new Linux kernel 5.8rc (not stable) using the mainline installer. Almost everything I tested worked fine except for Docker which would not start. Looking at the logs the issue seems to have to do with iptables.

Answer (score 2):

Switching from [iptables legacy to nftables](https://wiki.debian.org/iptables) fixed my problem. You can do that by running:

```
# update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-nft
# update-alternatives --set ip6tables /usr/sbin/ip6tables-nft
# update-alternatives --set arptables /usr/sbin/arptables-nft
# update-alternatives --set ebtables /usr/sbin/ebtables-nft
```

You can switch them back with:

```
# update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
# update-alternatives --set ip6tables /usr/sbin/ip6tables-legacy
# update-alternatives --set arptables /usr/sbin/arptables-legacy
# update-alternatives --set ebtables /usr/sbin/ebtables-legacy
```

Comment: Oh, that is what has been going on since 5.8-rc5, also causing `bpfilter: write fail -22` errors. Thank you.